# Redirect / Pipe wget download directly into gunzip

Tags: linux, gunzip

I want to download and to gunzip file.

```
  wget ftp://ftp.direcory/file.gz
  gunzip file.gz
```

Works fine.

However I want to simplify such command and tried this:

```
 gunzip <(wget ftp://ftp.direcory/file.gz)
```

wget downloads file, but gunzip task doesn't start.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: This will work with HTTP(S) urls but not FTP ones: `wget --compression=auto -O file.html https://.......`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try

```
  wget -O - ftp://ftp.direcory/file.gz | gunzip -c > gunzip.out
```

Read more the [wget documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html).

Comment: You need the -c parameter in order to have gzip output to the console, btw. Else it just overwrites its input.

Comment: The below does 3 things

`mkdir -p ${DIR} && curl -L http://apachemirror.wuchna.com/spark/spark-2.4.5/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz | tar zxv -C ${DIR} --strip-components 1`

1. Force creates the destination directory
2. UnArchives the archive to the given directory
3. Replaces the root directory with the given directory name by simply stripping down the archive's root directory.